# How to change Google Area Chart Overlap colour or opacity?

Tags: javascript, charts

Regarding Google Charts, is there a way to adjust the colour or opacity between two or more overlapping areas of an area chart? I've been attempting to modify Google's sample code provided at the [Area Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) development website. For convenience I have provided a copy of the sample code below. Note: If there isn't an officially supported way to do this I am interested in any dirty ways to go about it too.

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new
    google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

To help clarify what I hope to accomplish please see the following image.
[image]

Comment: Check 'areaOpacity' option. Default value is set to 0.3

Comment: Understand. I think there was already similar question here. The 3rd series was used with color white and opacity 1 to cut of overlapping parts.

Comment: I haven't found any other relevant questions yet. I'll keep looking (but I have scoured the tubes for examples, et. cetera). Adding a third entry into the series option yielded no results. You can try the code live here: code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/… - I simply copied and pasted the above code into the entry field and changed the function name to "drawVisualization".

Comment: Neither did I. That question I was referring was about nonoverlapping series which is not sutable for this problem. It cuts off just part of area. It could be used if points of intersection are found, but in that case also number of points on x-axis should be changed.

Comment: I'm appealing to the official  Google Charts team at Google Groups. If I make any progress I will update the information here for the sake of completeness. However, I have come to believe that there is no officially supported way to manipulate the graph like this. If that is the case I will make a request from the google charts team. Otherwise I will investigate alternatives like the old (deprecated?) chart API or alternative charting software. I'm also trying to find out if I can apply post processing to the generated SVG, but so far I haven't been able to make progress.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `series` with different `areaOpacity` to your options:

```
...
vAxis: {minValue: 0},
series: {
    0: { areaOpacity: 0.2},
    1: { areaOpacity: 0.7}
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misusing these options, they only affect each data set in its entirety. I am hoping to modify only the overlapping portions (e.g., overlapping portion set to 100% opacity) on the graph. I've updated my question to help clarify my question by adding a mock image.

Comment: Applying series: { 0: { color: 'green', opacity: 1}, 1: { color: 'blue'}, 2: { color: 'yellow'}} does not seem to affect the graph except for setting 'green' and 'blue'. I was interpreting your response as suggesting that I should apply a third series and that would select a third region (in this case the overlapping portions) of the graph. If so, adding a third region did not modify the graph.